# CSS transform on SVG text element not working in Safari

Tags: svg, safari, mobile-safari, css-transforms

Trying to position a battery indicator within a parent SVG.The SVG `<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24">` element has a path for the battery and a text element showing the percentage.Its being positioned with a couple of css transforms and text attributes.The text is correctly positioned when opening in chrome/firefox but goes offshoot in safari.

```
<text 
    text-anchor="middle"
    dominant-baseline="middle"
    style="transform:translate(50%,98%) scale(.2);
    font:700 13px sans-serif;fill:#deba78"
    >24.2%</text>
```

Codepen https://codepen.io/niwsa/pen/rNNBKEg?editors=1000

Comment: **UPDATE**: The issue is with translate on <text> element when percentage values are provided, Safari ignores that value.

Comment: maybe related to this bug: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=183237

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of translating the text you may give the text some attributes like x and y. Instead of scaling the text you may change the font-size.

For the path you may choose svg transforms like this:

```css
body {
  width: 200px;
}
.bg {
  fill: #beeb1b;
}
.cap {
  fill: #aaa8a9;
}
.trunk {
  fill: #231f20;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" tabindex="0" viewBox="0 0 351.33 722" aria-labelledby="bottletitle bottledesc" role="img">
    <title id="bottletitle">
        Bottle
    </title>
    <desc id="bottledesc">
        Bottle with battery indicator inside
    </desc>
    <g data-name="Layer 4" class="bg">
        <rect width="351.33" height="722" rx="23.33" ry="23.33"/>
    </g>
    <g data-name="Layer 3" class="cap">
        <rect x="146.81" y="60.9" width="57.71" height="73.67"/>
    </g>
    <g data-name="Layer 2" class="trunk">
        <path d="M173,153.25h57.75V223s1.08,25.33,30.41,56c27.06,28.29,35.34,60.33,35,71.33-.21,7,0,324.67,0,324.67s-3.33,7.33-9.33,7.33H117.12s-9-.33-9-6.66v-325s-.33-33,30.34-67c0,0,34.33-32.67,34.33-60.67S173.33,153.63,173,153.25Z" transform="translate(-26.46 -18.67)"/>
    </g>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24">
        <defs>
            <linearGradient id="lg" x1="0.5" y1="1" x2="0.5" y2="0">
                <stop offset="0%" stop-opacity="1" stop-color="#2ecc71"/>
                <stop offset="24.2%" stop-opacity="1" stop-color="#2ecc71"/>
                <stop offset="24.2%" stop-opacity="0" stop-color="#2ecc71"/>
                <stop offset="100%" stop-opacity="0" stop-color="#2ecc71"/>
                <animate attributeName="y2" from="1" to="0" dur="500ms" repeatCount="2s" fill="freeze"/>
            </linearGradient>
        </defs>
        <path fill="url(#lg)" d="M15.67 4H14V2h-4v2H8.33C7.6 4 7 4.6 7 5.33v15.33C7 21.4 7.6 22 8.33 22h7.33c.74 0 1.34-.6 1.34-1.33V5.33C17 4.6 16.4 4 15.67 4z" stroke="#fff" transform="scale(.5,.5) rotate(90,12 12) translate(45,-12)"/>
        <text text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="middle" style="font:700 2.5px sans-serif;fill:#deba78" x="12" y="23">
            24.2%
        </text>
    </svg>
</svg>
```

Comment: Looks good.Its even working with long text.Thank you for the quick fix.But the original css transform not working, could it be a browser bug?

Comment: @ninjaas seems so, why not report it so the Safari developers can fix it?

Comment: @enxaneta A great example of how to find a useful solution

Comment: @RobertLongson Filed a bug https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=202588

Comment: Wow the case still fails even in Safari Tech Preview, and the bug report is still in status "New". The workaround of x/y/fontSize is just that, a workaround, which crosses from CSS transforms and variables into attributes, which is often not desirable (you want to use CSS custom properties, CSS transition/animation etc)

Comment: its bad way to fix.

Answer (score 9):

Wrap the `<text>` element into a `<g>` element and apply the CSS transform on *that*, it happens to work currently even in Safari. This way, it's still CSS, so CSS transitions, animations, custom properties, selector based styling, continuous font scaling etc. work.

Comment: Wrapping with <g> is the simplest workaround for me. Thanks! Sad still not fixed in Safari...

Comment: Great workaround, fixed my problem too! Still not fixed in Safari...

Comment: Huge thanks! Solved my problem on Safari