# when using safari, svg text element transform-origin is different

Tags: svg, text, safari, transform

There is a difference in how svg of the same code is displayed when checked in chrome and safari.

```html
<svg width="600" height="600" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="svg4"
     style="border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); overflow: hidden; position: relative; float: left;">
    <rect width="100" height="100" x="300" y="300" fill="red"
          style="transform-origin:50px 50px;transform: rotate(-40deg);"></rect>
    <text x="300" y="300" text-anchor="middle" fill="#000000" font-size="40px" font-style="normal"
          style="transform-origin: 50px 50px;transform: rotate(-10deg);"
    >
        <tspan dy="0">jon doe 10</tspan>
    </text>
    <text x="300" y="300" text-anchor="middle" fill="#000000" font-size="40px" font-style="normal"
          style="transform-origin: 50px 50px;transform: rotate(-20deg);"
    >
        <tspan dy="0">jon doe 20</tspan>
    </text>
    <text x="300" y="300" text-anchor="middle" fill="#000000" font-size="40px" font-style="normal"
          style="transform-origin: 50px 50px;transform: rotate(-30deg);"
    >
        <tspan dy="0">jon doe 30</tspan>
    </text>
    <text x="300" y="300" text-anchor="middle" fill="#000000" font-size="40px" font-style="normal"
          style="transform-origin: 50px 50px;transform: rotate(-40deg);"
    >
        <tspan dy="0">jon doe 40</tspan>
    </text>
    
    <text x="300" y="300" text-anchor="middle" fill="#000000" font-size="40px" font-style="normal"
          style="transform-origin: 10px 10px;transform: rotate(-10deg);"
    >
        <tspan dy="0">jon doe 10</tspan>
    </text>
    <text x="300" y="300" text-anchor="middle" fill="#000000" font-size="40px" font-style="normal"
          style="transform-origin: 10px 10px;transform: rotate(-20deg);"
    >
        <tspan dy="0">jon doe 20</tspan>
    </text>
    <text x="300" y="300" text-anchor="middle" fill="#000000" font-size="40px" font-style="normal"
          style="transform-origin: 10px 10px;transform: rotate(-30deg);"
    >
        <tspan dy="0">jon doe 30</tspan>
    </text>
    <text x="300" y="300" text-anchor="middle" fill="#000000" font-size="40px" font-style="normal"
          style="transform-origin: 10px 10px;transform: rotate(-40deg);"
    >
        <tspan dy="0">jon doe 40</tspan>
    </text>

    
</svg>
```

When checked in chrome, the transform-orgin value is applied and rotated.

[chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qi4r8.png)

When checked in Safari, the transform-orgin value is not applied at all and is displayed the same.

[safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDEUn.png)

However, this phenomenon is only seen in the text of the svg element, and elements such as rect are normally displayed.

Is there any way to ensure that the transform-orgin is applied normally in Safari?

Comment: Apparently there is a bug. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58230668/css-transform-on-svg-text-element-not-working-in-safari As an alternative solution you can wrap the text in a group and transform the group